# can't update values in mysql using html and php

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, forms

I am trying to make a form using html and php to update mysql database. the database updates (autoincrements) the keys, but it does not add any of the strings to the values. i have searched people with similar problems but because their codes are different than mine I cannot understand it (i am a noob with php and mysql) I think my problem is in the way that i use the html to get the values but I could be wrong

```
<form action=submitform.php method=GET> 
     Name:<input type="text" name="cuName" size=20 maxlength=20><br>    
     Password:<input type="password" name="password" size=20 maxlength=45><br>
     Account:<input type="text" name="account" size=20 maxlength=45><br>
     Phone:<input type="tel" name="phone" size=10 maxlength=10><br>
     Email:<input type="text" name="email" size=20 maxlength=45><br>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

and my php is

```
<?php
        mysql_connect(localhost,  myUsername, "myPassword");
        mysql_select_db(myDatabaseName);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Customer (cuName, password, 
                        account, phone, email)
                    Values('$cuName', '$password', '$account',
                            '$phone', '$email')");
        echo $cuName ." thank you for reserving!";
        print ($cuName);
    ?>
```

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is relying on `REGISTER_GLOBALS` to be turned on; it is usually turned off for security reasons.

You should replace `$cuName` with `$_GET['cuName']` to get the values that are sent from the form.

Additionally, you should escape any value that is going to the database otherwise you may be exposing yourself to an SQL injection vulnerability.

Cleaning up your code for both these scenarios, results in something like this:

```
<?php
        if (!mysql_connect(localhost,  myUsername, "myPassword")) {
              print 'There was an error connecting to the database'.mysql_error();
              exit(); 
        }
        if (!mysql_select_db(myDatabaseName)) { 
              print 'Could not select db. The error was: '.mysql_error();
              exit();
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO Customer (`cuName`, `password`, `account`,`phone`,`email`)";
        $query .= "VALUES (";
        $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cuName'])."','";
        $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password'])."','";
        $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['phone'])."','";
        $query .= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email'])."'";

        if (!mysql_query($query)) {
            print 'There was an error inserting '.$query.'. Error was '.mysql_error();
        } else {
            echo $_GET['cuName']." thank you for reserving!";
        }
        print $_GET['cuName'];
    ?>
```

I also added some error checking. You should always check results of functions that rely on external systems (such as databases) because you never know what is the status of the database (it could be down, not working, etc.) So you should always check and print any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't define any of your GET values anywhere. $cuName, etc are not defined.

Each value needs to be associated to the $_GET.  IE,

`$cuName = $_GET['cuName']`

But you also need to make sure you don't insert data that hasn't been cleaned to prevent SQL injection. An example of this is:

`$cuName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cuName']);`

So, try this:

```
<?php
        mysql_connect(localhost,  myUsername, "myPassword");
        mysql_select_db(myDatabaseName);

        //Define Variables
        $cuName = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cuName']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']);
        $account = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['account']);
        $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['phone']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Customer (cuName, password, 
                        account, phone, email)
                    Values('$cuName', '$password', '$account',
                            '$phone', '$email')") or die (mysql_error());
        echo $cuName ." thank you for reserving!";
        print ($cuName);
    ?>
```

Comment: Don't forget the obligatory use mysqli_* comment.

Comment: I just tried what you told me, but for some reason my database is getting the update but no names, passwords, etc. it just increments my autoincrement key.

Comment: i did, but I', getting the same results. my database grows with empty rows.

Comment: Sorry!!!! It seems I forgot to upload the code to my server but now it works flawlessly! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Better to use:

```
$cuname = $_GET['cuname'];
```

like this....
Because your form method is on "GET",and my advise is to POST data than GET.